# Understanding why the following ODE has no ordinary point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have the following ODE

$$ y' = |x| y $$

My book states that $\mathbf{no}$ $x$ is ordinary in this equation since $|x|$ is nowhere analytic in complex $x-$plane.

Im a bit confused. I thought $|x|$ is only non-differentiable at the origin, but if $|x| \neq 0$, then we could have ordinary points by definition. What am I missing here?

#### Def: For the ODE

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n y^{(n-i)} p_{n-i}(x) = 0 $$

We say $x_0 \neq \infty$ is $\mathbf{ordinary}$ if the coefficients $p_i(x)$ are all analytic in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate what it means for $x$ to be ordinary?

Comment: I updated with definition

Comment: I think what Hans said earlier is the fact that the real-valued function $|x|$ does not extend to an analytic function on  $\mathbb{C}$ because if it did then there is some analytic function $f(z)$ such that $f(z) \big|_{\mathbb{R}} = |x|$, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big difference between real and complex differentiability. The function $f(z)=|z|$, $z \in \mathbf{C}$, isn't differentiable anywhere in the complex sense (the Cauchy–Riemann equations aren't satisfied).

Comment: I understand, but then the differential equation makes no sense since it is written for real values. Does he mean $y' = |z| y $? But, this does not make sense at all

Comment: @Hans I know $|x|$ cannot be extended to an analytic function in a neighborhood of $x=0$, but it seems to me that when $x\neq 0$ we have that $|x|$ is either $x$  or $-x$ which seems to be extendable.

Comment: @JackyChong: $|x|=\pm x$ is only true if $x$ is a **real** number. But in the question it explicitly says the **complex** $x$-plane.

Comment: @HansLundmark When $x>0$, the $|x| = x$ which could be extend to $z=x+iy$. I'm not too clear on this.

Comment: @JackyChong: For complex numbers $x=x_0+ix_1$, the absolute value is $|x|=\sqrt{x_0^2+x_1^2}$, which is not an analytic function of $x$. The question is talking about the complex $x$-plane, so this is what is meant by the notation $|x|$.

Comment: @ILoveMath: The equation isn't written for real values. (At least that's my interpretation, since you say that the author is talking about the complex $x$-plane). If you prefer to denote complex numbers by $z$, then yes, the equation is $y'(z) = |z| y(z)$. Which can't have any complex-analytic solutions $y(z)$, of course, since then the left-hand side would be analytic, but not the right-hand side. But I guess the point that the author is trying to make is that this is indeed a strange ODE to look at if one is interested in analytic solutions. What book are you reading?

Comment: Bender Orzsag Advanced mathematical methods for scientists and engineers

Comment: Great book! Wish I had time to read it properly myself... Anyway, they say very explicitly higher up on the same page (p. 62) that $x_0$ may be complex and that the coefficient functions $p_k(x)$ are assumed to be defined for complex $x$. The theory of Fuchsian equations really concerns functions of complex variables; see here, for example: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fuchsian_equation